# Probability and Equations in $\mathbb Z_p^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbf{A}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}_p^m$, where $p$ is prime and $|\mathbf{A}|=n$.

Given $\upsilon _1 , \upsilon _2  \in \mathbf{A}$, with $\nu  \in \mathbb{Z}_p^m,   \kappa  \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ uniformly at random, what is the probability that $\nu\cdot \upsilon _1\equiv_p \kappa$ and  $ \nu\cdot \upsilon _2\equiv_p \kappa$ ?

Comment: i know that if v1=av2 for some a in Zp (a not equal to one) the condition does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

What is the $\mathbb{F}_p$-dimension of the kernel of the map $\mathbb{F}_p^m\to \mathbb{F}_p^2$ sending $\nu\in\mathbb{F}_p^m$ to $\left(\nu\cdot \upsilon_1,\nu\cdot \upsilon_2\right)$?  What is the rank of this map?  What is its image?  The answer depends on $\upsilon_1$ and $\upsilon_2$.  (I'm not sure how $\textbf{A}$ and $n$ are relevant in this problem.)